# Post to server from Android

Tags: android, post

Get was quite simple, but I cant seem to get my head around POST. I need some help with sending an image and an int value to server.
this is the query that I have to perform:

```
http://example.com/webservice/?value=[{


 "table": "images",
  "operation": "insert",
  "params": [
    {
      "img_id": (int)         
      "img_path": (varchar)   
    }
  ],
  "transactionCompleted": true
}]
```

How can I post these to the server's database?
Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post json object with OkHttp from Square and Gson from Google.

[OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

```
public static final MediaType MIME_JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

JsonArray form = new JsonArray();
JsonObject item = new JsonObject();

item.addProperty("table", "images");
item.addProperty("operation", "insert");
item.addProperty("transactionCompleted", true);

JsonArray params = new JsonArray();
JsonObject paramItem = new JsonObject();
paramItem.addProperty("img_id", id);
paramItem.addProperty("img_path", path);
params.add(paramItem);

item.add("params", params);

form.add(item);

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MIME_JSON, new Gson().toJson(form));
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
    .url("http://example.com/post")
    .post(body)
    .build();

okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
    }
@Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
    }
});
```

Comment: this needs to be inside an AsyncTask ?

Comment: @kinsell No. You don't have to run it inside AsyncTask. OkHttp handles it for you.

Comment: JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
                    json.addProperty("img_id", imageId);
                    json.addProperty("img_path",imagePath );
                    JSONArray paramArr = new JSONArray();
                    paramArr.put(json);
                    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
                    obj.addProperty("table","images");
                    obj.addProperty("operation","insert");
                    obj.addProperty("params",paramArr.toString());
                    obj.addProperty("transactionCompleted",true);

Comment: is this how I add the json?

Comment: @kinsell You should use Gson instead of built-in JSON library. It is more fast and reliable.
Using Gson library you can add an array like below.
JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
JsonArray arr = new JsonArray();
arr.add(ITEM);
obj.addProperty("json_property", "proerty");
obj.add("json_array", arr);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96751/discussion-between-kinsell-and-harry-kim).

Comment: can you give me an example for GET, with the same query?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) by @koush.

POST:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("foo", "bar");

Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/post")
.setJsonObjectBody(json)
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
   @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
        // do stuff with the result or error
    }
});
```